# delete duplicates in sql: you can't specify target table 'table' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to delete all my records duplicate from my mysql table. I'm trying this but I have followint error:

> You can't specify target table 'maTable' for update in FROM clause.

I have already see another subject about this but I want you to see what I'm doing wrong with my queries and how can I make it work

```
DELETE 
FROM maTable 
WHERE id_table IN (SELECT id_table 
          FROM maTable GROUP by id_table 
         HAVING COUNT(id_table)>1)
```

Comment: @JulienBlanchard You are incorrect - `Count(id_table)` with a `Group by id_table` will return the number of occurrences of `id_table`.  It will *not* always be 1.

Comment: Note that you're *not* deleting just the duplicates - you're deleting *all* the rows that have a duplicate. This may or may not be what you want.

Comment: @Luaan this is what I want, I record a duplicate in a temporary table then with this query I delete all the rows that have a duplicate and insert the data in temporary  table after in my table _maTable_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the `IN` query in a subquery:

```
DELETE 
FROM maTable 
WHERE id_table IN (
   SELECT id_table 
   FROM (SELECT id_table 
         FROM maTable 
         GROUP by id_table 
         HAVING COUNT(id_table)>1) AS t)
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ec862/1)

Answer (score 2):

This is a limitation in MySQL.  One way around it is to use a `join`:

```
DELETE m
    FROM maTable m JOIN
         (SELECT id_table, COUNT(*) as cnt
          FROM maTable
          GROUP BY maTable
         ) mm
         ON mm.id_table = m.id_table
    WHERE cnt > 1;
```

If you want to delete all but one of the duplicates (that is, keep one of the values), then it is best to have some sort of unique column, such as a creation date:

```
DELETE m
    FROM maTable m LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT id_table, min(creation_date) as mincd
          FROM maTable
          GROUP BY maTable
         ) mm
         ON mm.id_table = m.id_table AND m.creation_date = mm.mincd
    WHERE mm.id_table IS NULL;
```